# MeanJS Internal server error 500 when trying to post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, meanjs

I am getting this error in the console when I am trying to insert a new record into the database.

> "POST http://localhost:3000/api/task 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Here's the function:

```
addTask(newTask) {
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/task', JSON.stringify(newTask), { headers: headers })
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Here's the server side code for post:

```
     //Save task
    router.post('/task', function() {
      var task = req.body;
      if (!task.title || !(task.isDone + '')) {
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
          "error": "Bad Data"
        });

      } else {
    db.tasks.save(task, function(err, task) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)

      }
      res.json(task);

    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: Show server side code as error 500 is from your server side only.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side route and http call are different. In your http call you are looking for the route `/api/task`, but your router is exposing the route `/task`. You can either add `/api` to the beginning of your route, or have your client side call the `/task` route instead.

Comment: I have changed the route to /api/task and now I got a 404 error.